# Drupal 7 views_datasource output only the json instead full html page

Tags: json, drupal-7

I using Drupal 7 and views_datasource.

I created a new view and set the Format as JSON data document. I also set a path to this view and let say /json-output.

When I access this /json-output it will display the full html page together with the json in the body.

My question is how to I retrieve only the json without the full html?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the configuration of your Views display which produces the
   JSON output.
2. Click on the Settings link of the JSON data document
   format. Make sure that Views API mode is not enabled.

The explanation

> Not using View API mode means the JSON gets output directly and the
>   server ceases normal page processing. Using it means the server does
>   not cease processing after outputting the JSON. This allows the Views
>   API to be used with the view without having to prematurely terminate
>   page processing.